# Wrong integer math in WebGL shaders

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, precision

I am using WebGL and custom shaders. In the fragment shader I need to do some precise integer math in order to index a tiled texture.

I seem to get rounding errors however, for some values, e.g. on the Ipad 4. Are *integer operations implemented in terms of floats*?

As a proof of concept, I tried the following shader:

```
const int eleven = int(11.0);

highp float f(const int nr11)
{
    if (int(nr11 / nr11) != 1)
        return 1.0;
    return 0.0;
}

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(f(eleven));
}
```

[Here](http://glslsandbox.com/e#26720.5) is a runnable link.

The shader produces a **black** background on my desktop, but a **white** one on my IPad. Can somebody explain me what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, webgl uses glsl 1.00 shaders, which isn't required to implement real integers.

You can read about it on page 19:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf

You won't be guaranteed true integer support in webgl for the time being.

Comment: Moreover, GLSL ES 3.0 (which brings integer support) is available only as part of OpenGL ES 3.0, which requires hardware support. So even once WebGL 2 (based on GLES 3.x) comes along, you probably won't be able to use new shader features like integers on devices like the iPad 4 that don't support ES3. (iOS device support for ES3 is the same as that for Metal: it requires at least an A7 GPU.)